# Developing renewal equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing-theory, renewal-processes

Customers arrive in a bank according to the Poisson process $N = \{ N(t); t\geq 0\}$ having rate $\lambda.$ There is only one teller in the bank who can serve only one customer. Thus any arrival that occurs while the teller is busy serving a customer is lost. A arrival which occurs while the teller is idle is accepted and the teller begins serving the customer. The service times form a sequence of $iid$ variables $T_1, T_2, \ldots$ independent of $N.$ Set
$$Z(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if a teller is serving a customer at time } t \\
0 & \text{if a teller is idle at time } t\end{cases}$$
For $t\geq 0,$ set $$m(t) = P\{Z(t) = 1\}.$$ What is the renewal equation for $m$?

My take is the following:
\begin{align*}
m(t) = E[N(t)] & = \int_{0}^{\infty} E[N(t)\big|T_1 = s ] f_T(s) ds\\
& = \int_0^t [1+m(t-s)] f_T(s)ds, \text{ if } s<t\\
& = F_T(t) + \int_0^t m(t-s)f_T(s)ds
\end{align*}
I don't know whether this is correct. I need help, any explicit solution is welcomed.

Comment: I don't see how $m(t)=\mathbb E[N(t)]$ follows, aside from $m(t)=0$ on $\{N(t)=0\}$.